# JS как расшифровать blob | WebSocket nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Отправляет все хорошо, но когда сообщение выводится на клиентах, оно выводится как blob - как его перевести в текст?).

server.js - nodejs

```
var http = require('http');
var Static = require('node-static');
var WebSocketServer = new require('ws');

// подключенные клиенты
var clients = {};

// WebSocket-сервер на порту 8081
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({port: 9000});
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

  var id = Math.random().toString().replace(".", "");
  clients[id] = ws;
  console.log("Новое соединение: " + id);

  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('Получено сообщение: ' + message);

    for(var key in clients) {
      clients[key].send(message);
      console.log('Сообщение отправлено клиентам: ' + message);
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Соединение закрыто: ' + id);
    delete clients[id];
  });

});

console.log("Сервер запущен на порту 9000");
```

[image: Все хорошо отправляет]

А вот client.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <!-- форма для отправки сообщений -->
    <form name="publish">
      <input type="text" name="message"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
    </form>
    
    <!-- здесь будут появляться входящие сообщения -->
    <div id="subscribe"></div>
    
    <script>
if (!window.WebSocket) {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'WebSocket в этом браузере не поддерживается.';
}

// создать подключение
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.1:9000");

// отправить сообщение из формы publish
document.forms.publish.onsubmit = function() {
  var outgoingMessage = this.message.value;

  socket.send(outgoingMessage);
  return false;
};

// обработчик входящих сообщений
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  var incomingMessage = event.data;
  showMessage(incomingMessage); 
};

// показать сообщение в div#subscribe
function showMessage(message) {
  console.log(message);
  var messageElem = document.createElement('div');
  messageElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
  document.getElementById('subscribe').appendChild(messageElem);
}

    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Клиент мне выдает какие-то blobы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В консоли у объекта виден метод "text", может вызвать нужно?

Comment: Нет, message.text не помогает

Comment: `message.text()` это же метод, а не свойство

Comment: Тогда дает другой блоб. Cейчас залью скрин

Comment: Чтобы добавить что-то - отредактируйте свой вопрос (кнопочка "править"). Насчет промиса,  "ws.on('message', function(message)" сделайте функцию async, а перед `message.text()` напишите await.

Comment: `async function showMessage(message)`  и `await message.text()` выдает нужный текст в console.log, но в страницу встраивается все равно blob

Comment: `clients[key].send(message);`, а сюда то вы тоже вставили `await message.text()`?

Comment: А вот, заработало, туплю. Спасибо!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить текст из Blob объекта, нужно воспользоваться методом `text`, который возвращает Promise. Дабы не проводить данную операцию для каждой отправки, мы можем перед этим присвоить переменной результат и использовать уже его.

```js
var http = require('http');
var Static = require('node-static');
var WebSocketServer = new require('ws');

// подключенные клиенты
var clients = {};

// WebSocket-сервер на порту 8081
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({port: 9000});
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

  var id = Math.random().toString().replace(".", "");
  clients[id] = ws;
  console.log("Новое соединение: " + id);

  ws.on('message', async function(message) {
    message = await message.text();
  
    console.log('Получено сообщение: ' + message);

    for(var key in clients) {
      clients[key].send(message);
      console.log('Сообщение отправлено клиентам: ' + message);
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Соединение закрыто: ' + id);
    delete clients[id];
  });

});
```